# All the data on the server is lost

Tags: google-compute-engine

Due to the insufficient performance of the server, I tried to adjust the server hardware. After the adjustment, I was prompted that there was a limit on the number of CPUs, so I needed to apply for a quota.

Server CPU and RAM can not meet the requirements > shutdown > adjust hardware > unable to power on, prompt quantity limit > Modify back > power on > hard disk unable to mount > all data lost.

I restart. I didn't pay attention to the Google cloud documents.(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd) 。

All my data was lost.

I am so depressed. What should I do? I'm dying

Comment: So? Take your backup. No backup - consider not working with servers. Backups are as basic as it gets. ZERO excuse.

Comment: Voting to close. Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Backups ARE standard.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows you trying to mount a raw block device rather than a partition on a block device. Have a look with gdisk, see what partitions it shows. Then try to mount those. If they aren't showing up in /dev but gdisk shows them, run partprobe and look again.

If it was a local instance SSD, however - you are probably out of luck. :-(